# Loading image with Django

Tags: python, django

For some reason I cannot get my images to upload with Django.  The models are saving the filename but saving the file in my media folder.

This is my **Model**

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name    ='Quiz Title',
        max_length      = 50
        )
    description = models.TextField(
        blank           = True,
        null            = True,
        verbose_name    = 'Quiz Description'
        )
    pool = models.ForeignKey (
        Pool,
        verbose_name    = 'Category of Quiz',
    )
    categories = models.ManyToManyField (
        Category,
        through         = 'QuizCategory',
        related_name    = 'category',
        verbose_name    = 'Category',
        help_text       = 'Categories in this Quiz'
    )
    live = models.BooleanField (
        verbose_name    = 'Quiz is Live?',
        default         = False,
    )
    logo = models.ImageField(
        upload_to       = 'logos',
        blank           = True,
        )
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.name)
```

This is my **AMENDED** **View**

```
def create_quiz(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = QuizForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            # file is saved
            form.save()
```

**EDIT**

And this is **FORM** declaration

```
class QuizForm (forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Quiz
        fields = ('name', 'description', 'pool', 'categories', 'live', 'logo')
```

**HTML**

```
        <form method="post" action="{% url 'create-quiz' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data" >{% csrf_token %}
            <input hidden name="id" value="{% if quiz.id %}{{quiz.id}}{% else %}0{% endif %}" readonly>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
                <input required type="text" name="name" {% if quiz.name %}value="{{quiz.name}}"{% else %}placeholder="Quiz Name"{% endif %} class="form-control quiz-search-box">
                <textarea required name="description" {% if quiz.description %}{% else %}placeholder="Quiz Description"{% endif %} class="form-control quiz-search-box">{% if quiz.description %}{{quiz.description}}{% endif %}</textarea>
                <select name="pool" class="form-control quiz-search-box">
                    {% for p in pool %}<option value="{{p.name}}" {% if quiz.pool.name == p.name %}selected{% endif %}>{{p.name}}</option>{% endfor %}
                </select>

                <h2>Questions</h2>
                <table class="table table-condenced">
                    {% for q in questions %}
                        <tr><td>{{q.name}}</td></tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% if quiz != 'new' %}
                        <a data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myQuestionModal' class="btn btn-primary">Add Question</a>
                    {% endif %}
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2 ">
                <span class="number-of-questions">
                    Number of questions in this quiz: {{questions|length}}
                </span>
                <span class="add-quiz-logo">
                    {% if quiz.logo %}
                        <img id="logo" src="/media/{{quiz.logo}}" width="150" alt="Logo spacer" />
                    {% else %}
                        <img id="logo" src="{% static '/img/no-logo.png' %}" width="150" alt="Logo spacer" />
                    {% endif %}
                    <input id="id_image" type="file" class="" name="logo" onchange="readURL(this);">
                </span>
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Save Quiz" class="btn btn-primary" />                   
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Help most welcome.  Thank you

Comment: Do you have Pillow installed?

Comment: We don't see your html, but do not forget to set enctype="multipart/form-data" in the <form> as described in the docs : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads

Comment: I had forgotten, but I've now added and still not working

Comment: You're never passing the file content itself. Why aren't you using Django forms as described in [handling uploaded files with a model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/file-uploads/#handling-uploaded-files-with-a-model)?

Comment: I've amended it to follow the link's approach but it still isn't working.  I'm about to add the html as well

Comment: I''ve got it.  The view needs to be `quiz.logo = request.FILES['logo']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dr Mouse solved this.  I forgot `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the `<form>`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of POST:

```
quiz.pool = Pool.objects.get(name=request.POST.get('pool'))
```

Try to use FILES:

```
quiz.pool = Pool.objects.get(name=request.FILES.get('pool'))
```

UPDATE:

Also you should to set up django to work with media files.
Add to settings:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'media')
```

and include media to urlpattern:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

After this you can insert image into your template with this:

```
<img src="{{ instance.logo.url }}"/>
```

Comment: I've tried using FILES instead of POST on the appropriate field but didn't work